# ng-init not working in AngulaJS

Tags: angularjs

Check my code:

JSON

```
var json = '[{"type":"product","id":1,"label":"Size","isRequired":true,"errorMessage":"","enablePrice":true,"description":"","placeholder":"Select Size","defaultValue":"","choices":[{"text":"Size 30","value":"Size 30","isSelected":false,"price":"$100.00"},{"text":"Size 32","value":"Size 32","isSelected":false,"price":"$100.00"},{"text":"Size 34","value":"Size 34","isSelected":false,"price":"$100.00"},{"text":"Size 36","value":"Size 36","isSelected":false,"price":"$100.00"}],"conditionalLogic":"","productField":"","basePrice":"$0.00","pageNumber":1},{"type":"option","id":2,"label":"Select Colors","isRequired":true,"errorMessage":"","inputType":"select","choices":[{"text":"Denim","value":"Denim","isSelected":false,"price":"$0.00"},{"text":"Black","value":"Black","isSelected":false,"price":"$0.00"},{"text":"Brown","value":"Brown","isSelected":false,"price":"$0.00"}],"enablePrice":true,"productField":1,"formId":24,"description":"","allowsPrepopulate":false,"inputMask":false,"inputMaskValue":"","labelPlacement":"","descriptionPlacement":"","subLabelPlacement":"","placeholder":"Select Jean Color","cssClass":"","inputName":"","adminOnly":false,"noDuplicates":false,"defaultValue":"","inputs":"","conditionalLogic":{"actionType":"show","logicType":"any","rules":[{"fieldId":"1","operator":"is","value":"Size 30"},{"fieldId":"3","operator":"is","value":"Regular"}]},"failed_validation":"","multipleFiles":false,"maxFiles":"","calculationFormula":"","calculationRounding":"","enableCalculation":"","disableQuantity":false,"displayAllCategories":false,"useRichTextEditor":false,"pageNumber":1,"displayOnly":""},{"type":"option","id":3,"label":"Select Fit","adminLabel":"","isRequired":true,"size":"medium","errorMessage":"","inputType":"select","choices":[{"text":"Regular","value":"Regular","isSelected":false,"price":"$0.00"},{"text":"Skinny","value":"Skinny","isSelected":false,"price":"$10.00"},{"text":"Fit","value":"Fit","isSelected":false,"price":"$5.00"}],"enablePrice":true,"productField":1,"formId":24,"description":"","allowsPrepopulate":false,"inputMask":false,"inputMaskValue":"","labelPlacement":"","descriptionPlacement":"","subLabelPlacement":"","placeholder":"Select Jean Fit","cssClass":"","inputName":"","adminOnly":false,"noDuplicates":false,"defaultValue":"","inputs":"","conditionalLogic":{"actionType":"show","logicType":"any","rules":[{"fieldId":"1","operator":"is","value":"Size 30"},{"fieldId":"1","operator":"is","value":"Size 32"},{"fieldId":"1","operator":"is","value":"Size 34"},{"fieldId":"1","operator":"is","value":"Size 36"}]},"failed_validation":"","multipleFiles":false,"maxFiles":"","calculationFormula":"","calculationRounding":"","enableCalculation":"","disableQuantity":false,"displayAllCategories":false,"useRichTextEditor":false,"enableChoiceValue":false,"pageNumber":1,"displayOnly":""},{"type":"option","id":4,"label":"Select Rise","adminLabel":"","isRequired":true,"size":"medium","errorMessage":"","inputType":"select","choices":[{"text":"High","value":"High","isSelected":false,"price":"$29.00"},{"text":"Low","value":"Low","isSelected":false,"price":"$0.00"}],"enablePrice":true,"productField":1,"formId":24,"description":"","allowsPrepopulate":false,"inputMask":false,"inputMaskValue":"","labelPlacement":"","descriptionPlacement":"","subLabelPlacement":"","placeholder":"Select Rise","cssClass":"","inputName":"","adminOnly":false,"noDuplicates":false,"defaultValue":"","inputs":"","conditionalLogic":{"actionType":"show","logicType":"any","rules":[{"fieldId":"1","operator":"is","value":"Size 30"},{"fieldId":"1","operator":"is","value":"Size 32"},{"fieldId":"1","operator":"is","value":"Size 34"},{"fieldId":"1","operator":"is","value":"Size 36"}]},"failed_validation":"","multipleFiles":false,"maxFiles":"","calculationFormula":"","calculationRounding":"","enableCalculation":"","disableQuantity":false,"displayAllCategories":false,"useRichTextEditor":false,"enableChoiceValue":false,"pageNumber":1,"displayOnly":""},{"type":"total","id":5,"label":"Total","adminLabel":"Total ","isRequired":false,"size":"medium","errorMessage":"","inputs":null,"formId":24,"description":"","allowsPrepopulate":false,"inputMask":false,"inputMaskValue":"","inputType":"","labelPlacement":"","descriptionPlacement":"","subLabelPlacement":"","placeholder":"","cssClass":"","inputName":"","adminOnly":false,"noDuplicates":false,"defaultValue":"","choices":"","conditionalLogic":{"actionType":"show","logicType":"any","rules":[{"fieldId":"1","operator":"is","value":"Size 30"},{"fieldId":"1","operator":"is","value":"Size 32"},{"fieldId":"1","operator":"is","value":"Size 34"},{"fieldId":"1","operator":"is","value":"Size 36"}]},"failed_validation":"","productField":"","multipleFiles":false,"maxFiles":"","calculationFormula":"","calculationRounding":"","enableCalculation":"","disableQuantity":false,"displayAllCategories":false,"useRichTextEditor":false,"pageNumber":1,"displayOnly":""}]';
$scope.attributes = json;
```

HTML

```
<div ng-repeat="conditions in attributes.conditionalLogic.rules">
   <select class="form-control" ng-init="option.id = conditions.fieldId" name="conditon_dropdown" ng-model="conditions.fieldId" ng-change="" ng-options="option.id as option.placeholder for option in attributes"></select>
</div>
```

Output

```
<select ng-options="option.id as option.placeholder for option in attributes" ng-change="" ng-model="conditions.fieldId" name="conditon_dropdown" ng-init="option.id = conditions.fieldId" ng-selected="conditions.fieldId" class="form-control ng-pristine ng-valid ng-not-empty ng-touched">
 <option value="?" selected="selected"></option>
 <option label="Select Size" value="number:1">Select Size</option>
 <option label="Select Jean Color" value="number:2">Select Jean Color</option>
 <option label="Select Jean Fit" value="number:3">Select Jean Fit</option>
 <option label="Select Rise" value="number:4">Select Rise</option>
</select>
```

I have tried both `ng-init` to selected my default option. But in my dropdown not populate. Please help me.

Comment: post your json from which you populate drop down

Comment: `conditions` variable may not have value when page load.. FYI `ng-init` called when it is compiling the DOM on which it has been placed..

Comment: @PankajParkar  `conditions.fieldId` I am getting `1`

Comment: is it hardcoded? or you are setting value from ajax success?

Comment: yes this is hard coded. So I am unable to post my JSON. :(

Comment: put your  code in  https://jsfiddle.net/

Answer (score 0):

You will have to initialise `fieldId` as string  like as-

```
$scope.fieldId='1';
```

because angularjs requires string value in `ng-model` filed in case of dropdown As per your requirement, you have to make `conditions.filedId` to string using `ng-init` like as -

```
<div ng-repeat="conditions in attributes.conditionalLogic.rules">
   <select class="form-control" ng-init="conditions.fieldId=conditions.fieldId.toString()" name="conditon_dropdown" ng-model="conditions.fieldId" ng-change="" ng-options="option.id as option.placeholder for option in attributes"></select>
</div>
```

I hope this will help you.

Comment: `conditions.fieldId=conditions.fieldId.toString()` this condition here I is coming false.

Comment: @chinu, coming false?? I didn't get your point. here i am just initialising conditions.fieldId to string.

Comment: Means my current value not selected.

Comment: @Chinu, can you make fiddle, so that we can check it properly.